# How do I tunnel audio over SSH?

Tags: server, ssh, tunnel

I am capturing sound on my MacBook and I have SSH access to a Linux Server. I want to be able to forward the audio through SSH to the Linux Server and do some processing on it, remotely.

Comment: You can send an audio file to a linux server and do whatever you want there. How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: You can forward ports with SSH, but you need to find yourself an application that can redirect audio to a TCP port on your Mac, and, on the other side, an application that can receive audio from a given port and store it to a file (or do whatever you need) with it on the Linux server side.